# How to find (unindexed) files in the current folder in Windows 10 File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, search, search-indexing

When in a folder in Windows 10, using the search panel to find files, one would expect an ad-hoc search of the file names in the current folder.

However, Windows only seems to find files that have been *indexed*. This is easily observed by rebuilding the search index, as search is effectively unusable for the first couple of minutes.

The question is, can you search the current folder in Windows 10 in a simple and straightforward way, regardless of indexing status?

Comment: Windows Search requires files be indexed.  You will have to use something other then Windows Search, if you want the capability of search for files, that have not been indexed.  File Explorer uses Windows Search just like File Explorer did

Comment: @Ramhound if the answer is "you can't", that's too bad, but it *is* an answer IMO so feel free to add.